# Is there way to randomize the join function in Python?

Tags: python, string, join, random

I'm using the `join` function to join words from a list into strings in Python.
Is there a way to use the choice/random function to randomize the choices into multiple different strings?

For example, now it does:

```
In [44]: sentence = ['this','is','a','sentence']
    ...: >>> ''.join(sentence)
    ...: 
Out[44]: 'thisisasentence'
```

And I would like to get:

```
'thissentence'
'isathis'
'thisissentence'
'isathis'
```

Comment: Look at the various functions available in the `itertools` package.  Since you aren't 100% clear on the output requirements (quantity of words desired), I suspect that you need a subset closure and perhaps some shuffling of those results.

Comment: It is not a problem that the second result string is the same as the fourth? (To be honest, that *is* a valid "random" result; an unshuffled string would also be valid, in this regard.)

Answer (score 2):

This might work. Note that in my solution `shuffle` is applied *in place*. If you want to run multiple times, just redefined `sentence` each time.

```
from random import shuffle, randint

sentence = ['this','is','a','sentence']

# step 1, shuffle sentence
shuffle(sentence)

# step 2, extract and join up to 4 elements
''.join(sentence[:randint(1, len(sentence))])
```

Comment: there is no need to hardcode the `4`. Go with `len(sentence)`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the choice that needs to be randomized, not the join. You could do that like this;

```
import random
sentence = ['this','is','a','sentence']
choice = random.sample(sentence, random.randint(1, len(sentence)))
print(''.join(choice))
```

Or for multiple results:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(''.join(random.sample(sentence, random.randint(1, len(sentence)))))
```